# How to maximize python efficiency?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, memory

I am working on a Code Signal practice interview question and my code passes 16/19 tests but the ones it is failing the rest due to exceeding the allowed time limit.

I tried using `set()` instead of a list but then the count method doesn't work, and since I'm extremely new to python I don't know a better alternative.

```py
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    list = []
    num = '_'
    for i in s:
        list.append(i)
    for i in list:
        if list.count(i) <= 1:
            num = i
            return num
    return num
```

Comment: Use a `Set`. Before you add a character check if it's not already there. The improvements that you'll get are: 1. search time in a Set is O(1) instead of O(n) in a list. 2. You don't have to iterate the list twice.

Comment: why do you copy the string to a list? why not just `for i in s:
        if s.count(i) == 1:
            num = i`

Comment: @Tomerikoo  I don't know Python but does everything that can be enumerated with a loop include a count member?

Comment: @alfasin how would you then know which was the first character as sets don't have order?

Comment: @alfasin "Before you add a character, check if it's not already there". So then, what will the resulting set inform you about? It will contain all of the characters from the string after processing the string. If you use two sets, you can do this: the first time a character is seen it goes to the `seen` set. If a character is already in the `seen` set, it goes to `seen_again` set.   The first non-repeating character is then the leftmost one which does not appear in the `seen_again` set. Or else a histogram dictionary could be used.

Comment: @junkinmunchkin You can use a dictionary which associates characters with their frequency of occurrence.

Comment: My bad, if he's counting the chars he can use a dict and simply count the occurrences. My miss was because of the first `return num` which bails out on the first character that repeats (which means that we totally ignore all the other repeated characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.7+, where dict keys are insertion-ordered, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    return next((char for char, count in Counter(s).items() if count == 1), '_')
```

With prior versions of Python, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` to keep track of the counts instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    counts = OrderedDict()
    for char in s:
        counts[char] = counts.get(char, 0) + 1
    return next((char for char, count in counts.items() if count == 1), '_')
```

so that `firstNotRepeatingCharacter('aababdcbcea')` returns: `'d'`

Both of the above code snippets have a time complexity of *O(n)*, as opposed to *O(n ^ 2)* in your solution due to your use of the `list.count` method in a loop.

Comment: upvoted. To make this a truly remarkable answer, edit in some links. Here they are ;) [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [orederedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dictionary to mantain counter of each character and check which char count is 1. This computes in O(N), your solution takes O(N^2) due to list.count() method

```
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    num = '-'
    d = {}
    for i in s:
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1

    for i in s:
        if d[i] == 1:
            return i
    return num
```